# Computational Efficient Hamming Distance Using `dplyr`

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to compute the (scaled) Hamming string distance
`d(x,y) = #{x_i != y_i : i = 1,...,n}/n` where `x` and `y` are strings of length `n`. I use R and dplyr/tidyverse and defined the Hamming distance as

```
hamdist = function(x,y) mean(str_split(x, "")[[1]] != str_split(y, "")[[1]])
```

This works perfectly fine. However, since I want to apply it columnwise, I have to use the `rowwise` verb (or use `map2` from purrr package). The problem: my data set contains ~50 mio observations and the calculations thus takes hours.

My question is therefore: is there a smoother/more efficient way to implement the Hamming string distance for column operations?

(dplyr solutions are preferable)

**An example:**

```
n = 1000
l = 8

rstr = function(n, l = 1) replicate(n, paste0(letters[floor(runif(l, 1, 27))], collapse = ""))

hamdist = function(x,y) mean(str_split(x, "")[[1]] != str_split(y, "")[[1]])

df = tibble(a = rstr(n, l), b = rstr(n, l))

df %>% mutate(dist = hamdist(a, b)) # wrong!
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(dist = hamdist(a, b)) # correct! but slow for n = 50 mio
```

Comment: Could you make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)?

Comment: I added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the `stringdist` package. Function `stringdist` takes a `method` argument that can be `"hamming"`. 
The `stringdist` package claims to be:

> Built for speed, using openMP for parallel computing.

Comment: thank you. This function in fact runs very fast:

`> system.time(df %>% mutate(dist = stringdist(a, b, method = "hamming")/8))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.002   0.000   0.001`
and
`> system.time(df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(dist = hamdist(a, b)))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.082   0.020   1.102 `

(for n = 10000)